# Variance of $X$ if $X_i\sim \operatorname{Ber}((\frac{r-1}{r})^m)$

Tags: probability

Let $X_i\sim \operatorname{Ber}((\frac{r-1}{r})^m)$. Knowing that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{r}\mathbb{E}[X_i]=r(\frac{r-1}{r})^m$, what is the variance?

Text uses a formula that I've never seen before: $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\sum_{i=1}^{r}\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]+2\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{j=i+1}^{r}\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]$.

Comment: Hint: expectation is a linear operator.

Answer (score 2):

Is $X = \sum_{i=1}^r X_i$?  Then
$$ X^2 = \sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{j=1}^r X_i X_j = \sum_{i=1}^r X_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^r \sum_{j = i+1}^r X_i X_j$$
and expected value of a sum is sum of the expected values.

Comment: Yes, it is. But I don't understand how to apply this formula.